# Elasticsearch Indexing Issue with Docker Compose Deployment

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, indexing, docker-compose, containers

I'm facing an issue with Elasticsearch and Kibana when deploying using Docker Compose. My application uses Elasticsearch to index data from an MS SQL database. I use Docker Compose to orchestrate my application, Elasticsearch, Kibana, and MS SQL in separate containers.

Locally, everything works as expected: when I spin up the containers, data gets indexed correctly in Elasticsearch. However, when deploying this on a remote server, the indexing doesn't seem to happen. In Kibana on the remote server, I don't see the index that's present on my local setup.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:      
      context: .
      dockerfile: /root/APP-LAWYERC/Dockerfile
    depends_on: [ mssql, elasticsearch ]
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /root/APP-LAWYERC/APP_LAWYER.WEB/wwwroot/images:/wwwroot/images
      - /root/APP-LAWYERC/Logs:/app/Logs

  mssql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    user: root
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "[HIDDEN]"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - /root/master.bak:/var/opt/mssql/backup/master.bak
      - mssql_data:/var/opt/mssql/data

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: els
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.1
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.7.1
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mssql_data:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

And here's the indexing script from my application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using APP_LAWYER.DAL.Entities;
using Elasticsearch.Net;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Nest;

namespace APP_LAWYER.BLL.Indexers
{
    public class ElasticsearchIndexer
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        private readonly ElasticClient _elasticClient;

        public ElasticsearchIndexer(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
                .DefaultIndex("subcategories");
            _elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
        }

        public async Task IndexSubcategoriesAsync()
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UOW>();

                var indexExistsResponse = await _elasticClient.Indices.ExistsAsync("subcategories");
                if (indexExistsResponse.Exists)
                {
                    await _elasticClient.Indices.DeleteAsync("subcategories");
                }

               
                var createIndexResponse = await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync("subcategories", c => c
                    .Settings(s => s
                        .Analysis(a => a
                            .Tokenizers(t => t
                                .EdgeNGram("edge_ngram_tokenizer", e => e
                                    .MinGram(1)
                                    .MaxGram(25)
                                    .TokenChars(TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Digit)
                                )
                            )
                            .Analyzers(an => an
                                .Custom("edge_ngram_analyzer", ca => ca
                                    .Tokenizer("edge_ngram_tokenizer")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Map<Subcategory>(m => m
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Properties(p => p
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(n => n.Name)
                                .Analyzer("edge_ngram_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(n => n.Description)
                                .Analyzer("edge_ngram_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(n => n.FullDescription)
                                .Analyzer("edge_ngram_analyzer")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );

           
                var subcategories = await uow.SubcategoryRepository.GetAllAsync();

                
                var bulkIndexResponse = await _elasticClient.BulkAsync(b => b
                    .Index("subcategories")
                    .IndexMany(subcategories));

                if (bulkIndexResponse.Errors)
                {
                    
                    foreach (var itemWithError in bulkIndexResponse.ItemsWithErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to index document {itemWithError.Id}: {itemWithError.Error}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue might be that Elasticsearch on the remote server isn't fully ready when my application starts the indexing process. How can I ensure that Elasticsearch is fully ready to accept data before the indexing starts? Has anyone faced similar issues or have any recommendations?

Thanks in advance for any insights!